# Generate random 28 × 28 grayscale images drawing a digit

Tags: python, neural-network, mnist

Is there any Python function which could generate an array for a 28x28 grayscale image representing a digit ? In other words the reverse of the MNIST-Keras example.

Comment: No, you would need generative function or write one yourself (e.g. GANs neural networks).

Comment: Oh ok ! Thanks for your answer! I'll check it